# Detached Garage rafter weight load of drywall and insulation

Tags: drywall, ceiling, garage, joists

Okay, I made a previous post about this and have determined my original plan is no bueno.  For light backstory, I've got a 3 car detached garage 40' x 25' with rafters every 4'OC (pictured below). I've been told I can't just hang drywall and insulation on them because of the fear they cannot hold the weight and will bow.  I contacted the builder and they do not have LL/DL specs for the build since it was built in 2000.

My newest crazy plan is to install support beams in the center of the rafters that run to the cement garage floor. It would be a bit unconventional because there would be a support pole in the middle of the room every 4 feet, but we think that we will be able to make it work.

If I did this, the plan is to run 2x4 perpendicular to the rafters 16" OC and then hang 1/2" lite drywall and R-30 insulation above that.  I've done the weight calculations and it would be adding 2.7 lbs/sqft not counting drywall mud.

Do ya'll think this will work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to do something significant structurally, you'll need a guy to sign off on it.  You should probably ask that guy what your options are.  That said it appears they only put a rafter on every second roof stud, so you can probably double the number of rafters easily for a start.  Its still nice and open, so you probably have lots of options for reinforcing the rafters as well.

Comment: @KH I'm trying to avoid adding rafters and everyone around me has prices to the moon with construction jobs like this. Supply is low, demand is high during this pandemic we are in.  That's why I'm thinking about the support beams.

Comment: Must your garage have a smooth ceiling?  I hope you've considered just insulating and leaving it at that.  What I see doesn't look hideous or need to be covered up.  You could leave it be until you have the means to do it properly.

Comment: If you add a beam on the center line you can add fewer teleposts in total and that would allow you to add studs on the 2 foot lines in between your current 4 foot lines. That should be enough support for drywall and insulation.  You still need to get the appropriate permits and you may need to pay someone to sign off on a plan.

Comment: I live very rural, so to my knowledge permits don't apply. At least people around here don't seem to think you need them on a detached garage not being utilized as living space.

Comment: @KH I like your idea of center beam.  I just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.  Center beam would run perpendicular to the rafters screwed into the current rafters.  Then add support poles, then add additional 2x6 joists running parallel to the current rafters to make them 2' OC, then the drywall and insulation.  If the above is correct, what would you recommend the center beam dimension be?

Comment: Also, strongly considering just insulating and leaving it like that.  How would I go about doing that? I currently have unfaced rolled insulation, I would still need to use some sort of strapping right?

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly dimension such a timber, so I would start by copying the existing rafter design to add identical rafters, and then use double 2x6 with staggered cuts for a beam.  Spray foam or spray fibre would do a good job, although you need a professional to make spray foam look nice and I've never seen rental spray fibre equipment so you'd need a professional there too.  Another option would be block foam, for which you adhere spikes to the surface first, then cut the foam to shape and impale it on the spikes, then put clips on the spikes to hold the foam.

Comment: Block foam could also be installed with strips of banding and wool type or block type insulation can be held up with poly or other plastic sheeting and staples.  Block is more fun and less itchy, but you could do wool type yourself as well.  The challenge with wool type is to get a sheet to stay in a 24" gap until you get plastic sheeting under it.  Easy with 16" studs but challenging with 24".